# The issue with access to twiiter via socioLib in Android

Tags: android, twitter

In my app I should use socioLib and write simple code to get access to twitter:

```
TwitterConnector twitter = SocialNetworkHelper
            .createTwitterConnector(CONS_KEY, CONS_SEC, CALLBACK);
    try {
        twitter.requestAuthorization(this);
        twitter.authorize(this);
    } catch
```

When I run this code I catch esception:

```
oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: api.twitter.com
```

Can you have idea where problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added internet permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Yes, I forgot about it. What a fool.

Comment: But now I catch NullPointerException in twitter.authorize(this);
. I can't get Request token. May be you know how to solve it?

Comment: not instantly, sorry - might be worth raising a different question for that